# C# if (strValue == "FALSE" | strValue == "TRUE")

Tags: c#

I have a string that contains a value of either TRUE or FALSE or null, this value is read from a text file which is outside of my control. What is the best way to use '|' with 'if'? Keeping in mind strValue could also be null, if strValue is null then I don't want to enter the if statement.

```
if (strValue == "FALSE" | strValue == "TRUE")
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Thanks

Comment: note that | is not the same as ||

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would seriously consider using `ToUpper` if it's out of your control - you never know when someone changes it to `"True"` or `"true"`.

```
if (strValue.ToUpper() == "FALSE" || strValue.ToUpper() == "TRUE") {

}
```

Regarding the responses about `ToUpper` and unnecessary defensive programming:

The original question said "read from a text file which is outside of my control", and "TRUE or FALSE or null".  As far as I know there is no universal way of indicating NULL in text files.  In CSV files, you could treat `,,` as `NULL` or `""` (empty string).  In fixed width text files, you could treat all spaces as `NULL`, `""` or `"<some spaces>"`, for example.

So the OP has already done some data conversion/interpretation to get to this point.

Comment: Actually, you should really use ToUpperInvariant

Comment: Alternatively you could use Convert.ToBoolean("TRUE") and use native boolean comparisons :)

Comment: I disagree. If the spec of the input format is defined as TRUE and FALSE, I'd not accept anything else deliberately... and by the way, `if (String.Compare(strValue, "FALSE", true) == 0 || String.Compare(strValue, "TRUE", true) == 0)` is a better approach.

Comment: @Chalkey: No you can't. `Convert.ToBoolean(null)` will return `false` so you can't distinguish between `null` and `false` only with its return value.

Comment: I think this solution is not even correct... in the case of strValue being null this surely will cause a null pointer exception on the call to `ToUpper()`...

Comment: Indeed, you will get a null reference exception.  I have no idea why this was accepted as the answer.  I only wanted to make the point that dealing with someone else's file you may need to be liberal in what you accept.

Comment: to echo what other have already said: this line has code smell that will give you some debugging headaches - NullReferenceException errors are somewhat difficult to debug if you don't understand what's going on under the covers.  Calling an instance method, like ToUpper(), on a null object will cause that exception.  You should use the String.Compare(string, string, bool), which will gracefully handle null references.  I am also down-voting this answer.

Answer (score 20):

```
if (strValue == "FALSE" || strValue == "TRUE") {
   // ...
}
```

to benefit from short circuiting. The second expression will not be tried if the first evaluates to `true`.

If you need case-insensitive comparisons:

```
if ("FALSE".Equals(strValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || 
    "TRUE".Equals(strValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
   // ...
}
```

Note that calling `.ToUpper()` or `.ToLower()` on `null` will throw `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Also note that if strValue is null, neither comparison will return true, so the OP's requirement WRT nulls is met.

Comment: Yes, have a look at the difference between operator | and operator || in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 4):

From your question, it sounds like all you REALLY care about is that the string is NOT NULL.  You then have two options:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue)) 
{
    //Do stuff with "TRUE" or "FALSE"
}
```

or, if you know it will NEVER be an empty string (""):

```
if (strValue != null) 
{
    //Do stuff with "TRUE" or "FALSE"
}
```

I would recommend the first choice.

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps:

```
if (strValue == "FALSE") {
    // do stuff
} else if (strValue == "TRUE") {
    // do other stuff
} else {
    // strValue was NULL or invalid.
}
```

Depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can put all of them into a single if statement:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue) && (strValue == "TRUE" || strValue == "FALSE")
{
  //do stuff
}
```

The first condition will be evaluated first, and then the others afterwards. I prefer to have the explicit null check, to help other probably less experienced developer to understand the code.

Comment: Hmmm... I understand your reasoning, but it sounds instead like a way to reinforce incorrect concepts in those less-experienced developers.  "Senior dev Bob did it that way, so it must be right."

Comment: Well, it's not just for the comparison operator, others suggested adding ToUpper() method call before comparing, that will definitely fail gloriously with NullReferenceException without the check.

Comment: The reason you check for null or whatever first is that it's safer.  That's something you want all your developers to learn.

Answer (score 0):

> > if strValue is null then I don't want to enter the if statement

If that *really* is the case then why are you worried about the "|" (bitwise or) operator.

You could just write:

```
if (strValue != "NULL")
{
}
```

What you *probably* mean is to use the (logical or) operator "||" on the true or false values.

```
if (strValue == "TRUE" || strValue == "FALSE")
{
}
```

I could keep guessing on the scenarios but I'm sure you get the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only three options "TRUE", "FALSE", "null", I recommend using the following:

```
if(String.Compare(strValue, "null") != 0){
  //do stuff
}
```

If you need a maximum compatibility and cannot rely on your input, you could switch strValue with strValue.toLower().